# Samsung Galaxy Note 1 /sdcard/ folder tree

Tags: adb, samsung-galaxy-note, shell, file-management

Hi I am searching for the factory folder tree for Samsung Galaxy Note 1.
I want the folder tree, so I can perform adb shell commands to access these directories. In a quest of recovering data.

e.g. `cd /sdcard/music/`

QtADB hangs. On ADB cmd prompt, there's nothing happening after following command.

[image]

Android commander needs root access too..

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you can't just get the tree using adb shell? Perhaps using something like `ls -R | grep ":$" | sed -e 's/:$//' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'` (Hang on, I'll get a cleaner command for you in a sec lol)

Comment: `find . -type d` also works. It's a lot simpler to put in, but its output isn't quite as readable. But yes, is there any reason why something like this wouldn't work for you?

Comment: As you either want to use ADB, you might wish to take a look at [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/), and use its integrated file manager.

Comment: @dotVezz my phone is softbricked. So the best I had managed so far is to access sdcard using shell function. Phone is only detected in adb via recovery mode. `find` doens't work. It says not found. I guess it's because phone is not entirely rooted. Seeming unbelievable case... `Su` is not found either.

Comment: @Izzy I am happy to use ADB. But as mentioned all I manage was going in $ mode into shell via `adb shell` and then trying to do `cd /sdcard/`. I can try out QtADB if it can recognize my phone or any similar workaround. Because I unable to find `Su` still

Comment: Is `ls` not found?

Comment: If your device is found by ADB, it is found by QtADB as well. And while root gives you additional possibilities, it's not a requirement for QtADB (at least not as far as I know). So just give it a try :) // Of course, you can also go the way dotVezz is just pointing: `ls` will always show you available files and directories in your current location, and `pwd` will tell you where you are.

Comment: @dotVezz the `ls` command is not denied. But no hierarchy is shown to me...I am trying to install QtADB and see if it works.. It's really strange, because device seemed to be rooted "PARTIALLY"....certain commands that should only work for root, it works...but certain ones don't work...

Comment: @Izzy I installed QtADB. But it too can't help much due to the fact I can't go in as Su.... can you help here please...

Comment: As my devices are all rooted, it's hard for me to check. You might want to take a look into the [QtADB FAQ](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/faq/) – I just did, and it seems it requires busybox on the Android device (which AFAIK, requires root). Sorry for that. Alternatives: [ADB Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbbrowser/), maybe [Android Master](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1273416) (if it doesn't require root as well), [Android Commander](http://www.modaco.com/topic/310462-android-commander-adb-gui/).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ADB GUIs available which might help you out. All of them have in common that you can browse the Android device's directory tree using a graphical frontend, and also execute "stuff" from a command-line interface ("console"). They might offer additional features as well:

- [Android Commander](http://www.modaco.com/topic/310462-android-commander-adb-gui/)
  [image: Android Commander]
  root optional (and only needed for Applications Manager and flashing options), Windows only. Offers an ADB shell (console) and a graphical file manager.
- [ADB Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbbrowser/)
  [image: ADB Browser]
  a GUI based file and application browser, Windows & Linux
- [QtADB](http://qtadb.wordpress.com/)
  [image: QtADB]
  seems to require root & Busybox. Multi-platform, multi-purpose GUI, including shell (console), file browser, app manager, system info, and much more.

Comment: I downloaded ADB browser, but I don't see anything when I ran the .exe....I dont think it can detect my device.